# Initializing a variable in a model from a angular service

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a image path from a restful call. I get a lot of other information that I do not need at the moment but I do need the path so I a loop through the image path on the HTML page. Below is what I have:

```
    [ {
  "level" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "description" : "SFG Level 0",
    "imageName" : "guru-level-0.png",
    "levelNumber" : 0,
    "created" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.687+0000",
    "updated" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.687+0000"
  },
  "levelImagePath" : "../../assets/images/level/guru-level-0.png"
}, {
  "level" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "description" : "SFG Level 1",
    "imageName" : "guru-level-1.png",
    "levelNumber" : 1,
    "created" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.689+0000",
    "updated" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.689+0000"
  },
  "levelImagePath" : "../../assets/images/level/guru-level-1.png"
}, {
  "level" : {
    "id" : 3,
    "description" : "SFG Level 2",
    "imageName" : "guru-level-2.png",
    "levelNumber" : 2,
    "created" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.690+0000",
    "updated" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.690+0000"
  },
  "levelImagePath" : "../../assets/images/level/guru-level-2.png"
}, {
  "level" : {
    "id" : 4,
    "description" : "SFG Level 3",
    "imageName" : "guru-level-3.png",
    "levelNumber" : 3,
    "created" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.692+0000",
    "updated" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.692+0000"
  },
  "levelImagePath" : "../../assets/images/level/guru-level-3.png"
}, {
  "level" : {
    "id" : 5,
    "description" : "SFG Level 4",
    "imageName" : "guru-level-4.png",
    "levelNumber" : 0,
    "created" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.693+0000",
    "updated" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.693+0000"
  },
  "levelImagePath" : "../../assets/images/level/guru-level-4.png"
}, {
  "level" : {
    "id" : 6,
    "description" : "SFG Level 5",
    "imageName" : "guru-level-5.png",
    "levelNumber" : 0,
    "created" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.694+0000",
    "updated" : "2017-08-14T11:14:43.694+0000"
  },
  "levelImagePath" : "../../assets/images/level/guru-level-5.png"
} ]
```

My model look like:

```
export interface LevelModel {
    level: {
        id: number,
        description: string,
        imageName: string,
        levelNumber: number,
        created: Date,
        updated: Date
    },
    levelImagePath: string
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LevelsProxy {

    constructor(private httpUtil: HttpUtil, private appConstants: AppConstants) { }

    getLevels(): Observable<LevelModel[]> {
        return this.httpUtil.get(this.appConstants.END_POINT_LEVELS)
            .map(response => <LevelModel[]>response.json());
    }

}
```

Now for the component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sfg-levels',
    templateUrl: './levels.component.html'
})
export class LevelsComponent implements OnInit {

    private levels: LevelModel[] = [];

    constructor(private levelsService: LevelsProxy) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.levelsService
            .getLevels()
            .subscribe((data: LevelModel[]) => {
                if(data){
                    this.levels = this.levelsService.getLevels();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

[image: component]

in HTML:

```
<picture>
    <img class="shield-holder" [src]="level?.levelImagePath" alt="image description">
</picture>
```

Error:

> /levels/levels.component.ts (23,21): Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'LevelModel[]'.
>     Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable'.

After a solution provided I have the following issue:

[image]

Comment: and what exactly is your error ?

Comment: @Faisal please see the updated question, thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you please put  at least two elements in json?

Comment: @micronyks the JSON is initialized. I am now getting an error saying `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for LevelsProxy!`  When I did this:
`this.levelsService
            .getLevels()
            .subscribe((data: LevelModel[]) => {
                if(data){
                    //this.levels = this.levelsService.getLevels();
                }
            });`

Comment: Yes that's why I asked you to complete your demo json data which is improper.

Comment: @micronyks my "DEMO" json is what is being returned from the backend.

Comment: but if you look at closely it is not proper. It doesn't have a closing bracket.

Comment: @micronyks come one. There is a bunch of data in that response. That is just one of an array of them. The JSON is not the issue. Lets delete these comments because they are not helpful towards the question.

Comment: You don't get it. I told you to update at least two elements from your array so someone can answer properly. Right now your demo json is invalid. I also understand its just a demo json but even in demo it should be proper.

Comment: See updated questions

Comment: Change `this.levels = this.levelsService.getLevels();` to `this.levels = data;`. And don't ignre typescript compiler errors. They tell you hat is wrong.

Comment: @micronyks It is saying `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` in the console.. Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.levelsService
        .getLevels(
        .subscribe((data: LevelModel[]) => {
            if(data){  
               this.levels=data.map( val => return val.levelImagePath);
               console.log(this.levels);
            }
        });
}

<picture *ngFor="let level of levels">
    <img class="shield-holder" [src]="level" alt="image description">
</picture>
```

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/Jf3HVZ8qg8pwzx01c13r?p=preview** 

(pls **ignore Angular version** and click on friends link to see the result. please find relevant code in myfriends.ts file.

Comment: Please see the picture I just added to the bottom of the question.

Comment: `this.levels=data.map( val => val.levelImagePath);` try to use it.

Comment: `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'LevelModel[]'`

Comment: If you dig little into your code, probably you'd be able to do it.

Comment: change private `levels:LevelModel[]` to `levels:Array[]` or `levels:any`.

Comment: did not work. Can we use zoom.us later, go to discussions and you can give me your email. I will screen share, I can do it at 6:00PM EST. Please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151908/discussion-between-micronyks-and-drew1208).

Answer (score 0):

In your example change this line:

```
 this.levels = this.levelsService.getLevels();
```

to:

```
this.levels = data;
```

TypeScript found this error for you.

Comment: When I do that I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`... Thank you for your time.